# What are some effective ways to last hit better?

Tags: league-of-legends

There are times, especially AD bot, when I think I am doing very well, hit Tab, and see that top lane has more CS than me. I usually hit around 150~ by the 20 minute mark, but I know I should be hitting a bit more.

How can I improve? How and when should I freeze the lane, and when should I push?

Comment: This is for DotA, but most of it still applies: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48555/how-can-i-improve-my-last-hitting-skill

Comment: Not at all, DotA champions actually have a variety of attack animation speeds, while League is primarily based on attack speed (attacks per second).

Comment: @Domocus LoL champions do too - just compare Le Blanc to someone like Annie or Sona.

Answer (score 9):

I've hit 95 minions at the 10 minute mark quite a few times while harassing, the way I do this is: of course you understand <kbd>s</kbd> stops you from moving or auto-attacking, press <kbd>a</kbd> and click on the minion before it dies.

People don't tend to watch when they are fighting that minions are dying, if you're not able to hit your opponent - for example, he got too far away - then it's best to go straight back to minion farming, instead of chasing when he has already gotten away. Doing this saves you 3-4 minions a fight - if you're the one living.

Also when 2 minions are dying at the same speed, take the health of 1 of them down a little more so you won't miss the other.

Other then that there really isn't much to say, well placed wards so you dont get ganked so when you're pushed up you still can farm perfectly fine.

Minions over harass ends up being a better late game strategy, unless it's fatal harassment that will make the bottom lose more than you would.

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few resources you can use!

http://solomid.net/guides.php?g=15558 - A solid guide to laning, goes over the nuances of each lane, last hitting, zoning, and freezing the lane.

http://www.lolpro.com/guides/game-play/166-game-play-guide-last-hitting - A guide that takes a different look at learning to last hit.

Comment: Please avoid just posting links; it will help if you can summarize the content there, or at least quote the most important bits here.

Comment: these links are rediculously helpful, thanks monsterpuff for posting these :)

Comment: Oak, thank you for the feedback. I will start putting in a summary to what each link goes to.

Answer (score 4):

OK. To start off, CSing is the single most important aspect of the game. So your question is extremely good and a very good one to ask to help you get better. As for a benchmark, Perfect CS is 100 at 10 minutes, but that's very very hard to do unless you are freefarming without getting harassed by your opponent.

What I do when I pick up a new champ is to go into a practice game and learn their auto-attacks and what abilities can get you last hits in a pinch without breaking your mana pool or whatnot. Usually I jungle, but when I do AP mid or bot I can get around 65-80 creeps by 10 minutes, which is fairly decent. Just get a feel for your damage early with boots and with a Dorans blade/ring and make sure you are comfortable with who you are playing.

As for freezing your lane, what it is is keeping the creeps in one spot just before your turret to ensure that you are safe to farm without overextending and risking a possible gank on yourself. For example, let your creeps fight the others while you sit idle and wait for the last possible second where you can farm, you will keep the creeps in the set spot that you want. As to when to freeze the lane is when you need a gank, and you have to force your lane opponent to push with their creeps so they dont get denied XP or potential gold.

If you get a successful gank or kill on your lane, *always* push your lane to their turret. Don't hit their turret, just push the creeps to it while they are not there. It denies them gold and XP and forces pressure for them to get back to their lane, even to make their jungle help their lane out and force him to steer away from his farm/other lane ganks.

So, in summary:

- Get a feel for the damage to what creeps you are last hitting, the auto attack animation for set champions
- Freeze when you need a gank
- Push hard when your lane opponent is forced back or is dead is the short version.